# Custom order by clause in postgres?

Tags: postgresql

I have 2 two tables as project_part and map_project_part
where project_part has following structure

```
Project_part_id Project_id  Module_id   Userinterface_id
1                 7           133          0
2                 8           134          90
3                 7           145          96
4                 7           120          0
5                 7           56           89
6                 7           65           40
7                 8           67           0
8                 7           80           33
9                 8           86           45
10                45           0            0
```

And map_project_part as

```
Map_project_part_id project_part_id task_id
1                       1            11
2                       2            11
3                       3            11
4                       4            12
5                       5            13
6                       6            14
7                       7            14
```

I want to fetch all data from project_part, but order by project_part_id desc where task_id=14 where task_id i will pass in query and task_id is in map_project_part table, so in output I want **(Mapped rows on top)**

```
 Project_part_id    Project_id  Module_id   Userinterface_id
    7                 8           67           0
    6                 7           65           40
    1                 7           133          0
    2                 8           134          90
    3                 7           145          96
    4                 7           120          0
    5                 7           56           89
    8                 7           80           33
    9                 8           86           45
   10                45           0            0
```

Comment: Sounds like a standard JOIN. Can you show us the query you tried?

Comment: select pp.project_part_id, pp.project_id, pp.area_of_work_id, pp.module_id, pp.userinterface_id 
from project_parts pp left join map_task_project_part mtpp on pp.project_part_id = mtpp.project_part_id
where mtpp.task_id=14 order by mtpp.task_id desc

Comment: This is wrong i know. It just returns single result where taskId matches

Comment: I the example I have stated, I have simplified it by removing few items from the original context like area_of_work etc. For better understanding

Comment: I think you're just missing an `OR mtpp.task_id IS NULL` (or put the `WHERE mtpp.task_id=14` clause in a subquery that you do the `LEFT JOIN` against)

Comment: It did not worked. Can you post what you have in mind.

Comment: Can you create a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12) with your example data?